# Is it possible to use JDBC to pass an Oracle collection that contains an XmlType?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, xmltype

How do I call a stored procedure using jdbc where the IN parameter is a nested table that contains a struct that contains an xmltype?

For example, what is the jdbc code to call p_my_package.insert_proc below using the thin driver and where the xml data may be greater than 4000 characters?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ot_config_info
AS
  OBJECT
  (
    config_id  VARCHAR2(512),
    config_xml sys.xmltype );

CREATE OR REPLACE type tt_config_list
AS
  TABLE OF ot_config_info;

CREATE OR REPLACE
PACKAGE p_my_package
IS
  PROCEDURE insert_proc(
      p_config_list tt_config_list);
END p_my_package;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
stmt = conn.createStatement();
```

String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO TABLENAME (ID, NAME, STUDENTXML)"+
" VALUES(?,?,XMLTYPE(?))";

pStmt = (OraclePreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(insertQuery);
pStmt.setObject(1, "001");
pStmt.setObject(2, "VIGILANCE");
pStmt.setStringForClob(3, "studentXMLString");

pStmt.executeUpdate();

Use ojdbc14.jar, download it from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-10201-088211.html)